# Extract words from review comments using R programming

Tags: r

Greetings!!
I am suppose to extract comments from a gaming site and then find out what exactly has people liked and disliked about the game.
I have achieved the first part of extracting the comments from the web pages and store them in a data frame.
Now I have columns like "Liked" and "Disliked" in my data frame. I want to fetch the specific words in the Liked and Disliked columns.

For eg:
Liked

"I like their website, it looks great in my opinion and I am feeling very good when the design attracts me in this way!So I signed up for an account, it took me only a couple of minutes and then I decided to make my first deposit here and to try my luck with Microgaming slots that are my favorite although sometimes I am losing serious amounts of money. Because they have a decent welcome bonus, I made a deposit of 25 euro via Skrill and I received 25 euro bonus. I want to say that this casino is very good in my opinion even if it’s first time when I am playing here.The welcome bonus impressed me, I will give a 10 because the wagering requirements are more than decent. Regarding their games, I have nothing bad to say because they have a lot of slots from different providers so I will give a 9. I recommend you this casino because it’s safe to play, it has lot of games and good welcome bonus!"

Disliked

"I wasn’t able to see any chat option, this would be the only bad thing!"

So from the like comment I want words like: good design, decent welcome bonus, safe to play.

And for Disliked: No chat option

Can this be achieved? Request you to kindly help me with this. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks and regards,

Ani

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this. 
You can select a range of factors (such as "like", "dislike", "hate", "love") which express best emotions and apply the code below.

```
z <- data.frame(group = c("liked", "disliked", "liked"),
            comment = c("I love this game", "I hate this game", "I like the game"))

results <- z %>% 
 group_by(group) %>% 
 summarise(positive_feedbacks = length(unique(comment[grepl("love|like", comment)])),
           negative_feedbacks = length(unique(comment[grepl("hate", comment)])))
```

This way you can count the amounts of positive and negative feedbacks to start with.